# Is it okay to sell Islamic software?

Tags: halal-haram, work, software

Is it okay to develop and sell a software that contains Islamic materials, for example, *Quranic duas, Ahadeeth, etc.*? My question stems from the belief that selling Quranic verses is forbidden. It's mentioned in Sura Al-Baqara ([2:41](http://quran.com/2:41)):

[image]

> **Sahih International**
>   And believe in what I have sent down confirming that which is [already] with you, and be not the first to disbelieve in it. And do not exchange My signs for a small price, and fear [only] Me.

Answer (score 2):

From the logical analysis and *dars-e-quran* :

It is not that you can't sell a Islamic software. Yes, you can. The printed Quran has been sold by the publishers since ages. Just to point out - various narrations/ translation of Quran by different Imam's are sold in hundreds of countries.

Now about the verse [Quran 2:41](http://quran.com/2/41) -

> And believe in what I have sent down confirming that which is
>   [already] with you, and be not the first to disbelieve in it. And do
>   not exchange My signs for a small price, and fear [only] Me.

If a scholar says, I would teach you this verse only if you pay me this much amount, then clearly this is the wrong thing and this is the things addressed here here i.e. 
*not exchange My signs for a small price* as we all know, The Quran was revealed in Arabic and hence such activities would come up in communities where the Word of God would spread but the people would not be Arabic speaking and might have a different native language.

Hope you are able to understand my point.

Comment: I am not sure I understand. From the verse it is clear that it is forbidden to sell the Quran. On the other hand, teaching someone and charging to do so is perfectly fine as you are providing a service. But you are claiming the opposite (selling quran is fine, teaching and asking for money is wrong)